# React, Redux-Toolkit: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

There is problem in setting redux store!
It cannot read that state.dataValue.data, says DataSlice is undefined.
Also in Redux Devtool no store have been setup
File: store.js

```
import rootReducer from "./slices";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
const store = configureStore({ reducer: rootReducer, middleware: [thunk] });

export default store;
```

File2: slice/dataSlice.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { dataSlice } from './dataSlice'

export default combineReducers({ dataSlice: dataSlice.reducer });
```

File3

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import store from '../store'
const initialState = {
  data: [],
};

const dataSlice = createSlice({
  name: "dataSlice",
  initialState,
  reducers: {

    setData(state, action) {
      const { data } = action.payload;
      state.data = data.map((item) => item);
  },
}
});
export const {
  setData,
} = dataSlice.actions;

export default dataSlice.reducer
```

File4 inventory.jsx

```
import {
  setData,
} from "../../slices/dataSlice";

const Inventory = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();


  const { data } = useSelector((state) => {
    return {
      data: state.dataSlice.data,
    };
  });
```

It showing that dataValue is undefined,
I am using React-Toolkit

Comment: Your reducer `setData`, that's even not valid syntax, please provide a reproducible working example. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The syntax appears valid - that's normal ES6 object literal function definition syntax.

Comment: @markerikson Can you please point out where the mistake is?

Comment: What does your `slices/index.js`  (or wherever you're creating the root reducer) look like?